# java smart card api support on IBM JRE

Tags: java, smartcard

I know Oracle JRE has Java Smart API implementation. However, if I try to use IBM JRE, it doesn't even ship with javax.smartcardio package.

Who know whether IBM JRE provide javax.smartcardio package and implementation or not? If so, where to get it?

Comment: Why don't you ask IBM? You obviously payed for.

Answer (score 0):

> Who know whether IBM JRE provide javax.smartcardio package and implementation or not? If so, where to get it?

IBM knows if they provide that particular package. If they provide it, they will know where you can get it. I presume IBM. IBM used to ship with their own (badly designed, but working) smart card library however.

Note that [JSR 268](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=268) specifies a package in the `javax` namespace. This means that implementation of the JSR is optional. You may be able to download and use a reference implementation from Oracle from their page. It states that the "RI" is available for free (although the testing kit costs about 50K$).

Comment: Tried to install the IBM JRE, but it failed to install without giving a reason, after leading me through a few download and setup screens that were *thoroughly* IBM (there is a reason why OS2 failed, and they still don't seem to know what it is)